# Controlling file naming pattern conventions on a file share

Tags: windows-server-2003, filesystems, file-sharing

We have a shared folder on a server, where sales managers ought to save incoming requests, invoices and other documents. Different types of documents separated by folders. Before now managers name files as they like, for example: *doc.number_date[dd.mm.yy]_company_name.[ext]* or *name-company-date[dd.month.yyyy].[ext]*, etc.

So we got kind of a mess there, and our branch's head set a task to clean everything up and implement file naming convention, like:
*date[yyyy-mm-dd]_name_doc.number_company_doc.type.[ext]* ﻿for every type of document. I'm certain that our employees, especially the elder one would make mistakes.

Is it possible somehow to control file naming at the moment of saving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I came across this feature, called File Screening Management (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732074.aspx). As it claims, it can be used for: "Define file screening templates that can be applied to new volumes or folders and that can be used across an organization". So, partially you can apply a file naming pattern, like "bill-*_*-*-*_*-*.*" or so. As far as I can see, it can't check naming with regular expressions, but this is at least something usable.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic case of trying to solve a people problem with a technical solution.

Is it possible? Not as standard, no.

Is there a workaround? Almost certainly, you could run a script or service to monitor the folder and rename things.

Should you? In my opinion, no. Any attempt to come up with some hacky solution will only lead to excruciating pain down the line, probably won't ever work properly anyway, and you'll then become responsible for the entire naming scheme.

Conclusion: It'a a management problem. The offenders need to be told to work properly and adhere to policy, just like any other workplace rules.

That said, it seems like you need a proper document management system. Some of them are very powerful, though they still require the user to use it properly!